# About a trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I play with Maple and i am interested about the  integral $\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {  \left( {x}^{2}+{z}^
{2} \right) }{{{\rm e}^{a\pi\,x}}-1}\sin \left( 2\,\arctan \left( {
\frac {x}{z}} \right)  \right) }\,{\rm d}x$

Where a and z both positiv number.

This integral seems complicated but i find the closed form and it is simply ${\frac {z}{3\,{a}^{2}}}$

But i don't have any idea how we can prove.
Can someone help me please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: This is a special case of a well-known representation of the Hurwitz zeta function. See [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula) Try let $x \mapsto \frac{2}{a} u$.

Comment: Of course but i don't understand why it's z/3a^2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin\left(2\arctan \frac x z\right)=2\sin\left(\arctan \frac x z\right)\cos\left(\arctan \frac x z\right)=2\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}=\frac{2xz}{x^2+z^2}$$
Thus
$$\begin{split}
\int_{0}^{+\infty }\!{\frac {  \left( {x}^{2}+{z}^
{2} \right) }{{{\rm e}^{a\pi\,x}}-1}\sin \left( 2\,\arctan \left( {
\frac {x}{z}} \right)  \right) }\,{\rm d}x &= \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{2xz}{e^{a\pi x}-1}dx\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}2xze^{-a\pi x}\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-na\pi x}dx\\
&=2z\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-na\pi x}dx\\
&= 2z\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2a^2\pi^2}\\
&= \frac {z}{3a^2}
\end{split}$$
where we used the [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) fact that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac 1 {n^2}=\frac{\pi^2} 6$.